# How to store binary data in a table and export it in a file?

Tags: binary, dolphindb

I have a file *xx.bin*. I want to read it and save its data in a table of DolphinDB. Which data type should I store it as?

After that, I want to export the binary data from the table in a file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readBytes` to read the data, and then use `blob` to store it. Then convert the binary data to STRING type. To export the data, you can use write to `write` the string data to a file:

```
// Read the original file.
source = "xxx.bin"
s = file(source)
len =  s.seek(0,TAIL)$INT
s.seek(0, HEAD)
a = s.readBytes(len)
s.close()

// Save the data to a table.
a1 = a.concat()
t = table(array(BLOB) as `testBlob) 
insert into t values(blob(a1)) 

// Read the data from the table, convert it to STRING type, and write it to a file.
binChars = exec testBlob from t
fout=file("xx1.bin","w");
fout.write(string(binChars[0]).toCharArray())
fout.close()

// Check if the two bin files are the same.
```

Comment: Presumably, a `.bin` file is **binary**, which means that you cannot convert it to a string. Binary files typically contain content that cannot be represented in a string, such as NUL and non-printable characters. Also, the question is totally unclear about what the actual content of the file is, and also asks multiple questions in the same post, which means it is too broad in scope. Answering it when it is in an unacceptable state removes all incentive for the OP to edit it to meet the site guidelines.